# Use iptables to load balance between multiple AWS elastic network interfaces

Tags: amazon-ec2, iptables, load-balancing, iproute2, policy-routing

Environment: Amazon EC2 m4.4xlarge, running Amazon Linux 2 AMI 2.0

I would like to use iptables to load balance https requests between a set of elastic IPs that are assigned to multiple Amazon elastic network interfaces attached to the same instance.

I have a load balancer working for a single network interface using a SNAT post routing scheme that round-robin's between all the IP addresses that are assigned to the instance. The nat table looks something like

```
Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
SNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             statistic mode nth every 5 tcp dpt:https to:xxx.xxx.xxx.xx5
SNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             statistic mode nth every 4 tcp dpt:https to:xxx.xxx.xxx.xx4
SNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             statistic mode nth every 3 tcp dpt:https to:xxx.xxx.xxx.xx3
SNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             statistic mode nth every 2 tcp dpt:https to:xxx.xxx.xxx.xx2
```

So far the approach I have taken to balancing between multiple IPs has been to mark packets in the output mangle table, policy route to network interfaces based off of the firewall mark, and then round robin on the interfaces. Here are the tables:

```
MANGLE:
Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 1518K packets, 63M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
   21  6007 CONNMARK   tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https CONNMARK restore
    4   240 MARK       tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https connmark match  0x1 MARK set 0x1
    4   240 MARK       tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https connmark match  0x2 MARK set 0x2
    4   240 MARK       tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https connmark match  0x3 MARK set 0x3
   12   720 RETURN     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https connmark match ! 0x0
    3   180 MARK       tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             statistic mode nth every 3 tcp dpt:https MARK set 0x3
    3   180 CONNMARK   tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             statistic mode nth every 3 tcp dpt:https CONNMARK set 0x3
    3   180 CONNMARK   tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             statistic mode nth every 3 tcp dpt:https CONNMARK save
    3   180 RETURN     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             statistic mode nth every 3 tcp dpt:https
    3   180 MARK       tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             statistic mode nth every 2 tcp dpt:https MARK set 0x2
    3   180 CONNMARK   tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             statistic mode nth every 2 tcp dpt:https CONNMARK set 0x2
    3   180 CONNMARK   tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             statistic mode nth every 2 tcp dpt:https CONNMARK save
    3   180 RETURN     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             statistic mode nth every 2 tcp dpt:https
    3   180 MARK       tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             statistic mode nth every 1 tcp dpt:https MARK set 0x1
    3   180 CONNMARK   tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             statistic mode nth every 1 tcp dpt:https CONNMARK set 0x1
    3   180 CONNMARK   tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             statistic mode nth every 1 tcp dpt:https CONNMARK save
    3   180 RETURN     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             statistic mode nth every 1 tcp dpt:https
```

```
NAT
Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 44028 packets, 3373K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    1    60 SNAT       tcp  --  any    eth0    anywhere             anywhere             statistic mode nth every 2 tcp dpt:https to:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx2
    1    60 SNAT       tcp  --  any    eth0    anywhere             anywhere             statistic mode nth every 3 tcp dpt:https to:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx3
    1    60 SNAT       tcp  --  any    eth0    anywhere             anywhere             statistic mode nth every 4 tcp dpt:https to:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx4
    0     0 SNAT       tcp  --  any    eth0    anywhere             anywhere             statistic mode nth every 5 tcp dpt:https to:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx5
    0     0 SNAT       tcp  --  any    eth0    anywhere             anywhere             statistic mode nth every 6 tcp dpt:https to:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx6
    1    60 SNAT       tcp  --  any    eth1    anywhere             anywhere             statistic mode nth every 2 tcp dpt:https to:xxx.xxx.xxx.xx12
    1    60 SNAT       tcp  --  any    eth1    anywhere             anywhere             statistic mode nth every 3 tcp dpt:https to:xxx.xxx.xxx.xx13
    1    60 SNAT       tcp  --  any    eth1    anywhere             anywhere             statistic mode nth every 4 tcp dpt:https to:xxx.xxx.xxx.xx14
    0     0 SNAT       tcp  --  any    eth1    anywhere             anywhere             statistic mode nth every 5 tcp dpt:https to:xxx.xxx.xxx.xx15
    0     0 SNAT       tcp  --  any    eth1    anywhere             anywhere             statistic mode nth every 6 tcp dpt:https to:xxx.xxx.xxx.xx16
    1    60 SNAT       tcp  --  any    eth2    anywhere             anywhere             statistic mode nth every 2 tcp dpt:https to:xxx.xxx.xxx.xx22
    1    60 SNAT       tcp  --  any    eth2    anywhere             anywhere             statistic mode nth every 3 tcp dpt:https to:xxx.xxx.xxx.xx23
    1    60 SNAT       tcp  --  any    eth2    anywhere             anywhere             statistic mode nth every 4 tcp dpt:https to:xxx.xxx.xxx.xx24
    0     0 SNAT       tcp  --  any    eth2    anywhere             anywhere             statistic mode nth every 5 tcp dpt:https to:xxx.xxx.xxx.xx25
    0     0 SNAT       tcp  --  any    eth2    anywhere             anywhere             statistic mode nth every 6 tcp dpt:https to:xxx.xxx.xxx.xx26
```

output of `ip rule`:

```
0:     from all lookup local
32501: from all fwmark 0x2 lookup if2
32501: from all fwmark 0x1 lookup if1
32602: from xxx.xxx.xxx.x12 lookup 10001
32603: from xxx.xxx.xxx.x13 lookup 10001
32604: from xxx.xxx.xxx.x14 lookup 10001
32605: from xxx.xxx.xxx.x15 lookup 10001
32606: from xxx.xxx.xxx.x16 lookup 10001
32612: from xxx.xxx.xxx.x22 lookup 10002
32613: from xxx.xxx.xxx.x23 lookup 10002
32614: from xxx.xxx.xxx.x24 lookup 10002
32615: from xxx.xxx.xxx.x25 lookup 10002
32616: from xxx.xxx.xxx.x26 lookup 10002
```

All the `lookup 1000x` rules are added automatically by amazon when attaching the ENI. The `fwmark` rules I added myself.

and if1 and if2 looks something like:

```
default via yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy dev eth2
yyy.yyy.yyy.0/20 dev eth2 scope link
```

The test I am running is hitting `curl https://ifconfig.me` which works for ~1/3 of requests. I am guessing this is because we receive the packet on the default `eth0` interface which knows how to properly deal with the packet.

The other 2/3s of requests are just hanging indefinitely. Its worth noting that the outgoing packets hit these tables and seem to do the right thing (namely the SNAT rules are changing the source IP addresses of outgoing packets). This has stumped me for some time.